# Parsing JSON file with excel but only certain rows

Tags: json, excel, parsing

I have a Hospital pricing JSON file that management wants me to parse but the file is over 4 million rows and as all of you know Excel can only handle 1 million lines. Fortunately, they only want pricing from a certain hospital group.  I know how to do a basic parse of JSON files using excel but don't know how to manipulate the parse so it only pulls down data matching a certain criteria.

Comment: You might be able to do this using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a specific question here so I'll give a broad answer. I don't think Excel is the right tool for the job here. You're better off using either a scripting or programming tool to filter out the rows from the JSON file that you need. You can then also reuse the script you wrote when another one of these questions comes in. A simple and easy to use contender here would be python and its `json` module.